# Selenium: Why .click() doesn't work in this case && how to check if a button is clicked?

Tags: java, junit, selenium-webdriver, safari

**Title edited**: was *"Selenium: How to check if a link is opened in a new tab?"*

I need to create JUnit test which should check if click on a button will cause opening some link in new tab.
Doing that I've faced the problem: **looks like .click() doesn't do what it suppose to.**
Here's the fragment of HTML:

```
<div class="small-5 column store-btns">
   <a class="google_play_btn" target="_blank" href="https://google.com">
      <img class="img-responsive"src="/s/img/buy/google_play_btn_blue.svg" alt>
   </a>
   <a class="app_store_btn" target="_blank" href="https://apple.com/">
      <img class="img-responsive"src="/s/img/buy/app_store_btn_blue.svg" alt>
   </a>
</div>
```

**EDITED:** Here's my simple JUnit test:

```
@Before
public void SetUp(){
    driver = new SafariDriver();
    pause = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2000);
}

@After
public void tearDown(){
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
}

@Test:
public void testLink() throws InterruptedException{
    driver.get("http://linktotestedpage");
    WebElement googlePlayButton = pause.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("google_play_btn")));
    googlePlayButton.click();
    List<String> browserTabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(browserTabs.get(1));
    String titleGP = driver.getTitle();

    Assert.assertTrue("Failure: link is ok", titleGP.equals("Google"));
```

I expect a new Safari tab to be opened after `googlePlayButton.click();`, but the driver just quits.
I see

```
IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1, Size 1
```

Where am I wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would add an additional check since the `windowsHandle` is explicitly unordered and there is no guarantee the last tab would be the one with index `1`

```
String currentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
List<String> browserTabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());

for (String handle: browserTabs){
    if (handle != currentHandle){
        driver.switchTo().window(handle);
        //perform addition action as needed;
        //when done close the window
        driver.close();
        driver.switchTo().window(currentHandle);
    }
}
String titleGP = driver.getTitle();
```

*Note: Untested code from my side*

Comment: I've got your idea but the thing is `googlePlayButton.click();` actually does not perform a click and no new tab is opened.

Comment: Then do a count on `browserTabs ` and see if that is more than `1`. Should not that be enough?

Comment: Sorry Saifur, I totally confused you by the title of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Just One suggestion, 
You may remove tearDown section of your code.
to leave browser open, to check whether tab is opening with any delay or not.
what i suspect is, you might be trying to switch to window before it is opened.

Note: should be a comment but don't have that reputation yet.

Comment: Thanks. The code works perfect in Chrome, but not in Safari. So this is browser/settings problem, I guess.